# Call a class constructor dynamically in c#

Tags: c#

I classes called classA,ClassB,ClassC. There is a string called className which holds the name of the class.. Instead of using bunch of If else statements, Is there any method to create new class like

new className()

Comment: [There is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d133hta4.aspx).. but what are you trying to do instead? there may be better alternatives to your approach

Comment: I have a dictionary of key and class names. Based on the value of key name I want to return the class objects to baseclass variable

Comment: @AbhinavKonda - Im struggling to ever find a reason you'd want to do that, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Activator class for the same

eg.

```
        Activator.CreateInstance<className>();
```

or

```
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(className));
```